# How can I check if my code will run in a new (or old) version of Node?

Tags: node.js, version

I have a code running in Node 9.8 
Node 9 will reach End-of-life soon.

If I switch to node 10,  how can I check if my code will run in node 10 without having to execute all paths of the code ?

Or if I go down to 8.11,  how can I check if my code will run in node 8.11 ?

There is no test cases written on the code.

Comment: Have you tried running your application tests (if any) on Node10? Maybe reading the breaking changes list? It's difficult to tell I guess, as most times you'll be using loads of external libraries. As far as I know, only a good battery of tests will help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example of why solid unit/integration tests are critical to long-term maintainability. That said, there are a few steps you can take to reduce the risk of breaking things:

- Take a look at the [change logs](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) pertaining to the versions you're moving to/from. The NodeJS team kindly includes a **Notable Changes** section in each change log, though I wouldn't rely on that alone as being 100% inclusive of the potentially breaking changes you may be up against.
- Consider writing unit/integration tests, both as part of your assurance that things won't break from this version change, as well as that things won't break from later version changes (or everyday changes for that matter).
- As much as I hate to say it, Googling around for guides on upgrading (or downgrading?) NodeJS versions may help you identify potential danger zones.

Generally, I'd consider it safer and better practice to upgrade the version than downgrade. For one, you're moving forward to the newer and greater experience the NodeJS team wants you work with, and secondly, future versions are probably more likely to be backwards compatible, whereas the old version may be missing features you're using.