# I will change the runtime to Node.js 18, but I'm concerned whether the function runs normally

Tags: node.js

We have AWS lambda function which runs on Node.js 14 runtime.
I will change the runtime to Node.js 18, but I'm concerned whether the function runs normally.
So I hope the code with code checker.

**Is there code checker for Node.js 18?**

Thanks,

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009827/how-can-i-check-if-my-code-will-run-in-a-new-or-old-version-of-node

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if my code will run in a new (or old) version of Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009827/how-can-i-check-if-my-code-will-run-in-a-new-or-old-version-of-node)